The custom dynamic plugins that i typed in tailwind isn't working can someone tell me why?
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily:{
        nerko: "Nerko One"
      },
      keyframes:{ 
        'bouncer':{
          '0%,100%':{transform: 'translateY(0)'},
          '50%':{transform: 'translateY(-50px)'}
        }
      },
      animation:{
        'bounce-50': 'bouncer 1s ease-in-out'
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({matchComponents, theme}){
      matchComponents(
        {
          circle:(value)=>({
            width:value,
            height:value,
            borderRadius:theme('borderRadius.full')
          })
        },
        {
          value:theme('spacing')
        }
      )
    }),
    plugin(function({matchComponents, theme}){
      matchComponents(
        {
            gradientShadow:(color) => ({
                boxShadow:`0 180px 700px -20px ${color}, 0 -180px 700px -20px ${color}, 180px 0 700px -20px ${color}, -180px 0 700px -20px ${color}`
            })
        },
        {
            color:theme('colors')
        },
      )
    })
  ],
}


Give above is the piece of code of my config.js file from tailwind where i tried to implement custom dynamic plugins but after that also non of the classes are shown in the html can someone please help me i have already set the input and output file and run it so that is not the issue so please help me
i tried rewriting the code and i tried different plugins but non of them show up so yea

It could be due to your gradientShadow rules. You pass the colors theme values, and assume that the values will be strings in the boxShadow property. However, you need to use flattenColorPalette() due to colors being an object of variable depth.
